# How to filter 'p' within an id of multiple id selection?

Tags: jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select multiple ids + an id that would select only paragraphs within that id

```
   $('#big8,#divmenu,#workstext.has('p')').each(function(i) {
      $(this).delay((i + 1) * 250).fadeIn(2000);
  });
```

The error i get is: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Comment: *An error*,  is there more than one???

Comment: Ok got that, edited to The error :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your code, the `.` in the `$('')` part means a class with the name that follows, also, you use `'` in this too, escape it or use double quotes, namely: `$("''");` or `$('\'')`.

Your code should be more like this:

```
$('#big8, #divmenu, #workstext').has('p').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay((i + 1) * 250).fadeIn(2000);
});
```

OR

```
$("#big8, #divmenu, #workstext").has("p").each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay((i + 1) * 250).fadeIn(2000);
});
```

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
$( "#big8, #divmenu" ).each( function ( i )
{
    $( this ).delay(( i + 1 ) * 250 ).fadeIn( 2000 );
} );

$( "#workstext" ).has( "p" ).each( function ( i )
{
    $( this ).delay(( i + 1 ) * 250 ).fadeIn( 2000 );
} );
```

Comment: 웃 this seems to select 'p' of every id (#big8, #divmeu, #workstext) whereas, i want to get only p of #workstext and select the rest of ids

Comment: Then your problem is your jQuery, you need to split it as there is not way to get *only one part with this but everything else without it* within a single selector

Comment: ok, i see.. would something like this be possible?
`$('#big8, #divmenu) && $('#workstext').has('p).each(function(i) {});`

Comment: Something like the edit is yes, but within a single jQuery statement, not as far as I know